# wordpress query trouble

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

### EDIT:

heres my file thats running the query maby its something else acting up - http://pastebin.com/4Cw3xMEM

---

this works as a direct query in SQLyog

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_type = 'post'
AND YEAR(post_date)=2010
ORDER BY post_date DESC;
```

it returns the three posts which are from 2010
but when i try run it via my wordpress it pumps out all the posts, regardless of date

i know theres a few things to be done so it selects the correct tables
and as far as i can gather, the following 'should' be alright

```
SELECT wposts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
AND YEAR(wposts.post_date)=2010
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC;
```

i really dont understand the ' wposts. ' at all, but it uses this sort of thing in the examples on wordpress codex

the ultimate goal is to make a query to pull posts froma certain year, and use that to make WP display groups of posts per year

i cant find anything that helps explain how to properly call the querys using the wordpress structure

if someone can explain a few of these things it might help alot, example,
with the following:

```
$wpdb->posts
```

i have no idea what '->' is for, i have only seen it used in php for assigning parts of an array in a foreach

- how do i get this thing to work?

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: `wposts.` - note `FROM $wpdb->posts wposts`. This means 'define an alias `wposts` for the posts table for this query', i.e. `wposts.post_date` means the post_date column frm the `$wpdb->posts` table. Usually used when you're joining two tables that have columns with the same name, e.g. id, to distinguish which one you mean. `wposts.*` means all columns from the `$wpdb->posts` table.

Comment: I think it's "please help me write a query to pull out all the WP posts grouped by year"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making this far too hard on yourself as I know all too well. When I started with WordPress I came to it as an advanced SQL developer so I wanted to code everything in SQL. Turns out though that you almost never need to use SQL with WordPress because it has it's own API with built-in URL-like query language complete with a caching system (the caching system means you don't need to optimize nearly as much as you might otherwise thinK.)

Here's a standalone file you can drop in the root of your website (call it `test.php` maybe?) so that you can test this out, fiddle with options and see it work:

```
<?php

include "wp-load.php";

$year = 2010;

$query = new WP_Query("post_type=any&posts_per_page=-1&year={$year}");
echo "<h1>Year: {$year}</h1>";
echo '<ul>';
foreach($query->posts as $post) {
    echo "<li>{$post->post_title} [post_type={$post->post_type}]</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

The query language I mentioned, extracted from above, looks like this:

> post_type=any&posts_per_page=-1&year=2010

You could also query in an array form, for example (it really just depends on your use-case and/or your preference):

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'year' => $year,
));
```

There are a lot more query parameters for `WP_Query()` than the three I used above. You can find the best documentation for those parameters here:

- [Query Parameters on the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Parameters)

Note that `WP_Query()` is just one way to query in WordPress. There's also `query_posts()`, `get_posts()` and you can interact with the query during *hooks* as well.

Yes, there are times when you need to drop to SQL but it's better in WordPress, especially for backward compatibility if you avoid SQL and use the APIs whenever possible.

Hope this helped.

-Mike

P.S. Want more info on the WordPress query? Let me suggest you ask questions over at [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) when it opens to full public beta in a week (WordPress Answers is from [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/), the same folks as StackOverflow.) WordPress Answers is more likely to get you better answers for WordPress than here because that site will be filled with WordPress experts as opposed the generalists (and otherwise extremely knowledgeable folks) here.

Comment: thanks so much +1 - i have it all sorted out now!
i never new about the URL query, this makes things so easy

Comment: Yes, it does make it easy, once you learn it. I still yearn for SQL at times because SQL is a tighter language with less special cases and more orthogonal to the app, but for maintainability it really makes sense to use the built-in database API.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

If later format works for you, use that instead. As for:

```
$wpdb->posts
```

The `->` is used with an object's properties and methods. In above case, `$wpdb` is an object which must have been created with `new` keyword by wordpress somewhere and `posts` is a property of `$wpdb` object that gets you all the post from the database.

Whether a class member is method or property is recognized with trailing brackets `()`. For example:

```
$wpdb->posts    // property
$wpdb->post()   // method
```

You may want to have a look at PHP OOP Basics:

- [Object Oriented PHP for Beginners](http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/)

Comment: ahhhhhh so its a property, im just so used to things like:
object.property that my brain didnt wanna recognize it as the same thing, ty for the link +1 but that still doesnt solve my database problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$wpdb->posts
```

this means `$wpdb` is an object and you try to acces the posts properties of the object.

I don't know anything about wordpress, but, if you want to use this syntax in a string (delimited by "), you should use

```
${wpdb->posts}
```

so try

```
$query = "SELECT wposts.* 
          FROM ${wpdb->posts} wposts, ${wpdb->postmeta} wpostmeta
          WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
          AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
          AND YEAR(wposts.post_date)=2010
          ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC;";
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR - shouldnt it be more like {$wpdb->posts} because $wpdb is a php variable... tested my way, still fails :(

Answer (score 0):

The $wpdb is a global object used in WordPress to contain things relating to the WordPress DataBase. The ->posts part means to fetch the 'posts' member of that object (or in other words a public variable). I can only assume it's the way you are calling the query that is causing the problem. You should be using something along the lines of...

```
$querystr = "SELECT wposts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
AND YEAR(wposts.post_date)=2010
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

foreach ($results as $r) {
    echo $r->title; // echo out variables from table
}
```

Comment: aside from the content of the foreach, my code is nearly identical, yet it still returns ALL posts regardless of date

Comment: What do you get if you echo out $querystr?

Comment: i get the SQL query, why would it be anything else?

Comment: oh you mean for the {$wpdb} part, it gives out the correct tables.

Comment: Well if the value you echo out works correctly when copy/pasted into a MySQL tool such as phpMyAdmin, then I don't see how $results can possibly contain more answers.